# Get Index Minimum Value in Column When String - Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, series

I have done some research on this, but couldn't find a concise method when the index is of type 'string'.

Given the following Pandas dataframe:

```
Platform | Action |    RPG    | Fighting
----------------------------------------
PC       |   4    |      6    |     9
Playstat |   6    |      7    |     5
Xbox     |   9    |      4    |     6
Wii      |   8    |      8    |     7
```

I was trying to get the index (Platform) of the smallest value in the 'RPG' column, which would return 'Xbox'. I managed to make it work but it's not efficient, and looking for a better/quicker/condensed approach. Here is what I got:

```
# Return the minimum value of a series of all columns values for RPG
series1 = min(ign_data.loc['RPG'])

# Find the lowest value in the series
minim = min(ign_data.loc['RPG'])

# Get the index of that value using boolean indexing
result = series1[series1 == minim].index

# Format that index to a list, and return the first (and only) element
str_result = result.format()[0]
```

Comment: Does ign_data['RPG'].idxmin() work?

Comment: It does, good sir :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **[`Series.idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html)**:

```
df.set_index('Platform')['RPG'].idxmin()
#'Xbox'
```

or what @Quang Hoang suggests on the comments

```
df.loc[df['RPG'].idxmin(), 'Platform']
```

**if `Platform` already the index:**

```
df['RPG'].idxmin()
```

**EDIT**

```
df.set_index('Platform').loc['Playstat'].idxmin()
#'Fighting'

df.set_index('Platform').idxmin(axis=1)['Playstat']
#'Fighting'
```

---

if already the index:

```
df.loc['Playstat'].idxmin()
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['RPG'].idxmin(), 'Platform']` would also work without `set_index`.

Comment: Alright so this definitely works, but I made a mistake while sanitizing the names of the columns and indexes. What I am looking for is in fact a way to get the column name whose value is the lowest for a specific index. So for 'Playstat' I should get 'Fighting'.

Comment: Should I just accept this answer and write a whole new question for sake of clarity?

Comment: You could check section EDIT, I think you only need `axis = 1`
If this does not solve your problem and it is more complicated, you should create a new question :)